# How to generate XML on MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, xml, xamarin.ios

I need to generate XML on MonoTouch application ? How i can create like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
...
</root>
```

I need to post the XML to web service as string format. And again I want to parse the response data. Response data also XML format string. I done it in j2me applications. But I don't know how to do this on MonoTouch?  Anyone tell me How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite API these days is the System.Xml.Linq API, look at the documentation and samples here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

For what you want, this is very easy:

```
  var s = new XDocument () {
      new XElement ("root")
  };
  Console.WriteLine ("The XML is: {0}", s.ToString ());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the XML by using the XmlWriter class.

The easiest way to parse XML would be to use LINQ.